# Centering Text on Android Canvas Including Accurate Bounds

Tags: android, text, android-canvas, centering

Here is the situation. I am rendering to a canvas. Nothing else is being rendered, the canvas is effectively fullscreen. There is only one view.

I want to make a simple (text) button. This consists of two parts: visually drawing it, and checking bounds to see if it is pressed. These two things should be consistent.

Ideally the centering is optional, though I would expect switching it to be simple.

After far too many hours, I suspect it is not simply an alignment issue, but also a use of the API that is the source of the problem.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Just use static layouts and then you can keep the text center aligned inside the canvas even if the size is increased by some limit by auto aligning the text.

```
        Rect bounds = new Rect(x1, y1, x2, y2);// set the bounds
        String textOnCanvas = "text to be wriiten";
        StaticLayout sl = new StaticLayout(textOnCanvas, textPaint,
                bounds.width(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, 1, true);
        canvas.save();
        float textHeight = getTextHeight(textOnCanvas, textPaint);
        int numberOfTextLines = sl.getLineCount();
        float textYCoordinate = bounds.exactCenterY() -
                ((numberOfTextLines * textHeight) / 2);

        //text will be drawn from left
        float textXCoordinate = bounds.left;
        canvas.translate(textXCoordinate, textYCoordinate);
        //draws static layout on canvas
        sl.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
```

The parameter **Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER** of static layout will take care of the center alignment of the text in canvas.